# Controlling when to transmit data using BIO_write()

Tags: c, network-programming, openssl

I've recently started using OpenSSL in my project.

Is there a way to instruct BIO_write(bio, buf, len) to transmit data when its internal buffer reaches a certain length?

I'm currently calling the function like this:

```
unsinged char *pByteArray;
Build pByteArray;
BIO_write(pByteArray);
```

But it'd be good if I could call the function like this:

```
BIO_write(Length bytes);
BIO_write(STX byte);
BIO_write(Data);
BIO_write(ETX byte); // Now transmit!
```

Comment: You could write a custom BIO to do this, but ultimately you'd be limited by your transport protocol.  If your BIO is attached to a TCP socket, for instance, then your network stack will control whether or not to send it all at once since TCP is a stream-based protocol and there's nothing you can do about it.  I don't really understand why you'd rather use BIO_write to build your message instead of building it in a buffer and calling BIO_write once anyway.